# What is the equivalent datatype for datetime of SQL Server 2008 in ADO?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado

The datetime datatype in SQL Server 2008 supports milliseconds.

I am trying to execute a stored procedure that accepts a datetime parameter, with an arg with milliseconds, as input/output value.

I am unable to convert the string that I pass in to the method as datetime value. When I do not pass in the millisecond values, the conversion happens correctly.

I see the conversion problem in the below method.

```
Set objpara2 = objCom.CreateParameter("datetime", adDate, adParamInputOutput, , "2011-01-01 11:01:01.123")
```

**What is the equivalent datatype for datetime of SQL Server 2008 in ADO?**

Here is the complete code snippet:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestProc] @time1 time, @datetime datetime output
as
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select @datetime = datetime from ALLTimeTypes where time = @time1;
end

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim objCon As ADODB.connection
    Dim objCom As ADODB.command
    Dim objPara As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim objpara2 As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim objRS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim k As Integer

    Set objCon = New ADODB.connection
    Set objCom = New ADODB.command

    objConConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;" _
         & "Data Source=ES-89W87BS;" _
         & "Database=MASTER;" _
         & "Integrated Security=SSPI;" _
         & "DataTypeCompatibility=80;" _
         & "User ID=sa;" _
         & "Password=<redacted>;"

    objCon.ConnectionString = objConConnectionString
    objCon.Open        
    MsgBox "Connection opened"

    With objCom
        .CommandText = "TestProc"     'Name of the stored procedure
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc  'Type : stored procedure
        .ActiveConnection = objCon.ConnectionString
    End With

    Set objPara = objCom.CreateParameter("time1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "02:02:02.3456123")
    Set objpara2 = objCom.CreateParameter("datetime", adDate, adParamInputOutput, , "2011-01-01 11:01:01")

    objCom.Parameters.Append objPara
    objCom.Parameters.Append objpara2

    Set objRS = objCom.Execute        
    objRS.Open
    Do While Not objRS.EOF
        For k = 0 To objRS.Fields.Count - 1
            Debug.Print objRS(k).Name & ": " & objRS(k).Value
        Next
        objRS.MoveNext
    Loop        
    ...
```

Comment: That is more than a snippet. You should try and pare your questions down to the minimum needed to demonstrate your issue so we don't have to read all that stuff. That will also make it less likely that you inadvertently post your `sa` password on the internet.

Comment: why oh why are you using "DataTypeCompatibility=80;" ????????

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=97), `adDBTimeStamp`

Comment: Even the adDBTimeStamp does not accept the milliseconds thing. I am seeing the issue with this too

Answer (score 2):

Apparently ADO is removing the milliseconds. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246438

I have not tried this but I think you should change the data type for your parameter in the stored procedure to varchar(23) and use a string parameter that looks like this `'2011-05-17T10:18:54.293'`.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you include a `T` in the string value between the date and time components?
 (like `2011-01-01T11:01:01.123`)

```
Set objpara2 = objCom.CreateParameter("datetime", adDate, adParamInputOutput,,
 "2011-01-01T11:01:01.123")
```